# Catalog Search Issue

Tags: magento2.2, catalogsearch

When I'm seraching product title **"Mixer, Ribbon, 25 CF, 304 S/st, 15 HP, New, HD, (2)"** on the website, then getting following error:-

```
2 exception(s):
    Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*', query was: INSERT INTO `search_tmp_5b97c02fa7b3d4_51710438` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  `eav_index`.`entity_id`, (((0)) * 1 + LEAST((MATCH (data_index) AGAINST ('Mixer* Ribbon* 25 CF 304* S st 15 HP New* HD 2 ribbon* mixer\"ribbon* blender\"*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)), 1000000) * POW(2, search_weight)) AS `score` FROM `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `eav_index`
     INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` AS `search_index` ON eav_index.entity_id = search_index.entity_id
     INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `cea` ON search_index.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
     INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_index` ON stock_index.product_id = eav_index.entity_id AND `stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `stock_index`.`stock_status` = 1 AND `stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1 WHERE (eav_index.store_id = '1') AND (`eav_index`.`attribute_id` = 85 AND `eav_index`.`value` in ('3', '4') AND `eav_index`.`store_id` = '1') AND (MATCH (data_index) AGAINST ('Mixer* Ribbon* 25 CF 304* S st 15 HP New* HD 2 ribbon* mixer\"ribbon* blender\"*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `entity_id` DESC
     LIMIT 10000
    Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'

Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*', query was: INSERT INTO `search_tmp_5b97c02fa7b3d4_51710438` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  `eav_index`.`entity_id`, (((0)) * 1 + LEAST((MATCH (data_index) AGAINST ('Mixer* Ribbon* 25 CF 304* S st 15 HP New* HD 2 ribbon* mixer\"ribbon* blender\"*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)), 1000000) * POW(2, search_weight)) AS `score` FROM `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `eav_index`
 INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` AS `search_index` ON eav_index.entity_id = search_index.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `cea` ON search_index.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_index` ON stock_index.product_id = eav_index.entity_id AND `stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `stock_index`.`stock_status` = 1 AND `stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1 WHERE (eav_index.store_id = '1') AND (`eav_index`.`attribute_id` = 85 AND `eav_index`.`value` in ('3', '4') AND `eav_index`.`store_id` = '1') AND (MATCH (data_index) AGAINST ('Mixer* Ribbon* 25 CF 304* S st 15 HP New* HD 2 ribbon* mixer\"ribbon* blender\"*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `entity_id` DESC
 LIMIT 10000
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Truncate the tables related to catalog search like catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1, catalogsearch_fulltext_scope2 etc and try again.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I've truncate catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1,catalogsearch_fulltext_scope2,catalogsearch_fulltext_scope3 but still getting issue.

Comment: @wakarAhamad : did you solved the issue? I am getting the same.