# Access denied problem after login

Tags: login, magento2.3.0, centos

I'm using `2.3` `centos7` `vpserver`

I have `Access denied` in `domaine.com/index.php/customer/account/` after login ?

How can fix it, please help!

exception.log

> [2018-12-30 18:27:04] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'XXX_sql_name1.inventory_stock' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `inventory_stock`.`stock_id` FROM `inventory_stock` {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'XXX_sql_name1.inventory_stock' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `inventory_stock`.`stock_id` FROM `inventory_stock` at /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'XXX_sql_name1.inventory_stock' doesn't exist at /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []

Comment: What about `logs` ? it's not an locked account ? try to create a new one then login

Comment: @PЯINCƏ please see original post, i updated the log. thank you!

Comment: tried but can't @PЯINCƏ

Comment: This error has no link with the `login access denied`, Try to `clean the cache` & `session`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` see if you have an error, then `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` then try

Comment: i have 3 magento but only 1 is working login. i think is Permission on cpanel or mysql? how can fix do you know? thank you! @PЯINCƏ

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans. Looks like it might be giving you a way to clear the catalogsearch_fulltext_scope3 table. Reindexing the search:index may help

Comment: Try to reindex all

Comment: Are you meaing this code in mysql `DELETE FROM catalogsearch_fulltext_scope3 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM catalogsearch_fulltext_scope3 WHERE datetime <= now() - INTERVAL 900 SECOND order by id) u;` thank you! @HerveTribouilloy

Comment: Tried but can't @PЯINCƏ `php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento cron:run
php bin/magento cron:run
php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Look this https://www.tigren.com/fix-deadlock-error-reindexing-magento-2/  be careful on manipulation, do before all a database backup

Comment: As Prince says, do make sure to have a way back. Having dev/staging environment is best. Do not delete any record in the database unless your indexes can't run (meaning your database is corrupted).

Comment: working on backend reindex all but i dont know why not working on command.anyway thank you for helpful!! @PЯINCƏ

Comment: working on backend reindex all but i dont know why not working on command.anyway thank you for helpful!!  @HerveTribouilloy and look at log i need run this ? DELETE FROM catalogsearch_fulltext_scope3 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM catalogsearch_fulltext_scope3 WHERE datetime <= now() - INTERVAL 900 SECOND order by id) u;

Comment: in magento 1, we were able to truncate search table, there is a thread mentioning the same with magento 2 at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241761/catalog-search-issue

Comment: @PЯINCƏ i getting backend Access denied in others magento, please help see the original post

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy  i getting backend Access denied in others magento, please help see the original post

Comment: has this issue been resolved?